# Can every element in the arbitrary space be converged to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

When I have for example $\mathbb R$ then I'm able to create a sequence which will converge to any of the elements in $\mathbb R$:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} &\rightarrow 0\\
\frac{1}{n} + 1 &\rightarrow 1\\
\end{align}

But, is this possible in every space? Or they exist some special elements in some spaces, which are "non-convergeable", while other elements in the same space can be converged to with suitable sequence?

Comment: how about defining the metric $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\neq y$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 Great comment - it deserves to be put into the answer ;-)

Comment: if your sequence is $x_n = 1/n + 1, x_n$ is not in $\mathbb N$,  But, you can always define a sequence $x_n = k, \forall n\in \mathbb N$  and it converges to $k.$

Comment: @DougM thank you, I corrected myself to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The heart of this question seems to be: For any element $x$ of the space, can we find _distinct_ points in the space that are arbitrarily close to $x$.  Which makes the hjhjhj57 comment interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because (whenever convergence makes sense) for every element $x$ in the space, the constant sequence $x$ converges to $x$